# Trying to create quantile dummy variables using loop in R

Tags: r

I have a series of variables given below:

```
id <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
v2 <- c(32, 12, 42, 12)
v3 <- c(5, 3, 2, 1)
df <- data.frame(id, v1, v2, v3)
```

I am trying to create dummy variables such that there are individual columns if the id variable's value for v1, v2, or v3 is in the 1, 2, 3, 4 quartile for the respective variable. I am currently doing this by calculating the quartiles and then hard coding the dummy variables using mutate. Is there a way to do this using a loop? The expected output is

```
id  v1 ... v1_quartile1 v1_quartile2 v1_quartile3 v1_quartile4
A   1      1            0             0           0
B   2      0            1             0           0
C   3      0            0             1           0
D   4      0            0             0           1
```

Comment: For the given example, can you please post an expected output?

Comment: I added an edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

```
library(fastDummies)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  mutate(quartile = as.integer(cut(value,
    breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(value, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))))), 
   .by = name, .keep = "unused") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  dummy_cols("quartile", remove_selected_columns = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = starts_with("quartile"),
    names_vary = "slowest") %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = "id")
```

-output

```
id v1 v2 v3 quartile_1_v1 quartile_2_v1 quartile_3_v1 quartile_4_v1 quartile_1_v2 quartile_2_v2 quartile_3_v2 quartile_4_v2 quartile_1_v3
1  A  1 32  5             1             0             0             0             0             0             1             0             0
2  B  2 12  3             0             1             0             0             1             0             0             0             0
3  C  3 42  2             0             0             1             0             0             0             0             1             0
4  D  4 12  1             0             0             0             1             1             0             0             0             1
  quartile_2_v3 quartile_3_v3 quartile_4_v3
1             0             0             1
2             0             1             0
3             1             0             0
4             0             0             0
```